# Is point exist in circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Let us consider `x and y` is a point and then make a `radius` of some value `r`.If suppose i had a `point a and b`, I need to check whether the point a and b is in the `radius r from x and y` or not. Can give me the formula to this solution,So that i can implement in c programming.

Comment: Distance formula $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\le r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $(a,b)$ is inside the circle of radius $r$ around $(x,y)$ iff $(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2<r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get rid of the square root as well.

Here is the distance formula:$$
d = \sqrt{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2}
$$

The point is in the circle, if $$d \leq r$$

So your formula is $$
\sqrt{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2} \leq r
$$

Just square it and you get $$
(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 \leq r^2$$
Since you can' t have a negative radius.

This is useful when you have lots of points, because you can get rid all of the square roots in trade of a single calculation of $r^2$. This is of course good only when you iterate over the circles, and check each point for each circle. Pseudocode:

```
for x, y, radius in circles:
    rs = radius * radius
    for a, b in points:
        if (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 <= rs:
            // The point is in the circle
```

If you have only a single point, the simple distance formula should be perfect too.

If you don't consider points on the radius of the circle to be in the circle, your formula is $d < r$. (By the way $d = r$ is the formula for point is exactly on the radius)

Comment: Though `d==r` may not work due to floating point precision.

Comment: @peterwhy yes! But floating point numbers are not necessary here or am I missing something? If all coordinates and radiuses are integers, no floating point operation is required. (Unless the numbers are too big)

Comment: Yea, so just a side note here. Your answer is perfectly fine.